# One-Sided Bivariate Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with finite means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y,$ finite variances $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2,$ and correlation $\rho.$ Let $A$ be the event that $X \leq \mu_X + k\sigma_X$ and $Y \leq \mu_Y + k\sigma_Y,$ where $k \gt 1.$ Using the one-sided univariate Chebyshev inequality, I can find this lower bound on the probability of event $A$ occurring: $$P[A] \geq {{k^2-1} \over {k^2+1}}$$ But this does not use the correlation. If the correlation is known, I am wondering how this inequality can be improved. What is the tightest bound possible if the correlation is known?

Comment: You may want to check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Two_correlated_variables

Comment: The Wikipedia article covers the two-sided cases, but does not address the one-sided.